# Centre subview that is larger than its superview with Visual Format Language

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to centre a subview (200 wide) within a smaller superview that is 100 wide. Using the constrains below, it ends up at x=-100 instead of x=-50.

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[statusLabel(200)]"
                                        options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX
                                        metrics:nil
                                          views:viewDict];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alignment constraints, like NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX are for aligning multiple sibling objects with respect to each other, not for aligning a single object with respect to its superview. To do that, you need to use…

```
NSLayoutConstraint *c = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.outerView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self.innerView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                  multiplier:1.f constant:0.f];
```